# Multiple table, array append/concat problem postgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, multidimensional-array

This is my first post and after searching and even trying to use the chatbots I still cant progress.

I'm trying to array_append or array_cat one text array called 'genres' in table artists, to an another 'genres' text array in the table 'event_data'. This is itself is not difficult, but what im trying to do is use the rows in the artists table, each with a genre array, and append the array to the row where the 'artist_name' in artists is found in another text array call called 'artists' in event data.

Please note that the order of the artist table is not the same as the events table so although you cant see the artist_name in the artists column in the snippet, its there, I just limited to 4 to keep it clean. Somewhat unsuccessfully

```
event_name                artists                            genres
manic.monday              ["SUNRISE_GROOVE"]               ["None"]
Traffic light Party       ["digital"]        ["Techno","Reggaeton"]
Xterrestrial Launch Party ["CNVNHausbr and xenophil"]   ["Techno","Tech House"]
THE UNKNOWN               ["Better Call Paul","Dicso_Muzek"]    ["None"]

artist_name genres
Dicso_Muzek ["None","Deep","(Deep,Electronic,Techno,House)"]
TiM TASTE   ["Progressive House","Tech House""]
Hausbrand   ["Techno","Tech House","(\"Hard Techno\""]
DAV3        ["Techno","Tech House","(Techno,House)"]
```

Thanks in advance for any help and teachings you can provide

I've tried these queries and more but i'm having issues with the sub-query returning more than one row,which it needs to. There maybe 10 artists in the event_data.artists array and a lot of artist_name rows with their genre arrays in the artist table.

```
UPDATE event_data SET genres = array_append(genres,
(SELECT genres FROM artists WHERE artist_name = ANY(
SELECT UNNEST(artists) FROM event_data)))::text;

UPDATE event_data
SET genres = array_cat(genres, (
SELECT array_agg(genres)
FROM artists
WHERE artists.artist_name = ANY(event_data.artists)))
FROM event_data;*/

UPDATE event_data
SET genres = array_cat(genres, (
SELECT genres
FROM artists
WHERE artist_name = ANY (event_data.artists)
))
WHERE artist_name IN (SELECT artist_name FROM artists)
```

I'm expecting to have each row of event_data to have all the genres from each artist in the genre array.
Because the artists[] string is inputted in a separate data scrape from the collection of the artist names, I haven't appended them in the process.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, its not pretty, but if it makes it easier to understand then great.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure it out. I used a temp table to join the arrays found in the artists table before inserting them into the other array

```
WITH temp_table AS (
SELECT artist_name, unnest(artists.genres) AS genre
FROM event_data
JOIN artists ON artist_name = ANY (event_data.artists))
UPDATE event_data
SET genres = array_cat(event_data.genres::text[], (SELECT array_agg(genre) FROM temp_table))
```